# how to find passphrase in an image .jpg?

Tags: image, passphrase

Is there any tool or software to find passphrases in an image like .jpg? or Should i use any programming in this regard, i googled but din't find any guidance?

Comment: You're trying to automatically beat CAPTCHAs?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean. Are you talking about encrypted messages in images (steganography)? There are planty of tools that claim to detect strganography messages in images. You can use them and try to extract the message. Most steganography techniques use additional encryption, but this is another story.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [bypassing a CAPTCHA](http://www.google.sk/search?hl=sk&safe=off&client=opera&hs=4mZ&rls=en&q=bypass+captcha+c%23&meta=&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=). Not a trivial thing, but you can read up on recognition of objects in images and [Optical character recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition).

p.s. are you trying to spam someone?

Comment: Maybe the OP edits the posts too much and got tired of SO's human verification, so the programmer's soul is saying "I need to automate this!"